# After child has been initialised, operation from parent component on child DOM causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I'd like to make some operation from parent component on child component after child component has been initialised.

### Parent:

```js
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('child') childComponent: ChildComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.childComponent.domMethod('boo');
  }
}
```

```
<p>parent</p>

<app-child #child></app-child>
```

### Child:

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,) {

  }
  public term = '';
  public items;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      { name: 'foo' },
      { name: 'bar' },
      { name: 'baz' },
      { name: 'boo' },
      { name: 'zoo' },
    ];
  }

  domMethod(value: string) {
    // const input = document.getElementById('childInput') as HTMLInputElement;
    // input.value = value;
    this.term = value;
    this.cdr.markForCheck(); // <-- enabling this line cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  }
}
```

```
<p>child</p>

<input type="text" id="childInput" [(ngModel)]="term">

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | search: term">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Link to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jntl6p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts) for reproduction

## Edit:

If I add `setTimeout` to the parent component, it works. Can I achieve it without `setTimeout`?

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.childComponent.domMethod('boo');
    })
  }
```

Comment: have you try `setTimeOut`?

Comment: Yes, `setTimeout` works. Just curious if it could be achieved without it

Comment: have you thing to go with `this.cdr.detectionChanges();`?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have use `detectionChanges` for this:

```
constructor(private _cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.childComponent.domMethod('boo');
      this._cd.detectChanges();

  }
```

Comment: from where to import `ChangeDetectionRef` ?

Comment: @OshanaDissanayake AppComponent

Comment: it should be as `ChangeDetectorRef` , right? not `ChangeDetectionRef ` ?

Comment: @OshanaDissanayake import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'; `private _cd: ChangeDetectorRef `

Comment: yeah ! In your answer above it says `constructor(private _cd: ChangeDetectionRef){}` :)

Comment: @OshanaDissanayake i have update my code have you solve your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188454/discussion-between-abhishek-and-oshana-dissanayake).