# "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"; I don't understand what type of operations which are inside the lifecycle hooks, make it to be thrown

Tags: angular, lifecycle-hook, angular-lifecycle-hooks

It's important to me due to certain reasons, to understand how Angular works; well;
One thing that I can't understand, is the error that's mentioned in the title, and what things I'm prohibited by Angular to do inside  the lifecycle hooks (if there are any).
Please answer here and do not forward to links; I think that I've checked all of them already.

Comment: look at this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072065/after-child-has-been-initialised-operation-from-parent-component-on-child-dom-c/54072543#54072543)

Comment: Do you have a sample piece of code that you're getting this error in?

Comment: I prefer an answer which explains the problem that the error message is intended for, in order to understand Angular better.
In my opinion, no need to provide code in order to answer my question :)

Comment: @IdanSteinberg ok i understand have you read this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained)?