# Angular detectChanges not working on child Component

Tags: angular, angular-material

Edit: I just don't know why, but change detection stop at the first child in the hierarchy. If I manually invoke change detection one level deeper (in `sch-job-detail`), then the values are updated.

I've built a `MatTable` with expandable rows.
The "expandable" row part is as follow:

```
<!-- Hidden cell -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let jobModel" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
        <div
            class="detail-cell"
            *ngIf="jobModel.isExpanded"
            [@detailExpand]
        >
            <sch-job-detail
                [jobModel]="jobModel"
                ...
            ></sch-job-detail>
        </div>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

As you can see, the table owns an array of `JobModel`(s), and each row receives its own `JobModel` instance.
`JobModel` is a wrapper for a `FormGroup`, which is also a "transposition" of a simple interface object `Job`.

`sch-job-detail` has others children Components, for example:

```
<!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="col">
    <sch-job-row-toolbar
        [isNew]="jobModel.isNew"
        [isEdit]="jobModel.isEdit"
        [isError]="jobModel.isError"
        [isValid]="jobModel.isValid"
        ...
    ></sch-job-row-toolbar>
</div>
```

On the expandable row I have a button which lets the user enter a new Cron expression, and that Cron expression is then added to the `FormGroup`'s `FormControl`.

Inside the `TableComponent`:

```
public addCronExpression(jobModel: JobModel): void {
    this.matDialog
        .open<CronDialogSmartComponent, any, string>(CronDialogSmartComponent)
        .afterClosed()
        .pipe(filter<string>(c => !!c))
        .subscribe(c => {
                jobModel.addCronExpression(c)
                this.changeDetector.detectChanges()
            }
        )
}
```

`JobModel#addCronExpression`:

```
public addCronExpression(cronExpression: string): void {
    const cronExpressions = this.formGroup.controls.cronExpressions
    cronExpressions.setValue([...cronExpressions.value, cronExpression])
}
```

As you can see, being that I do not change the `JobModel` instance, I run `detectChanges` to update the `TableComponent` and its children, `sch-job-row-toolbar` included I suppose!

The thing is `sch-job-row-toolbar` does not seem to recalculate its bindings (ngOnChanges doesn't run).

So those values:

```
[isNew]="jobModel.isNew"
[isEdit]="jobModel.isEdit"
[isError]="jobModel.isError"
[isValid]="jobModel.isValid"
```

are not changed.
We can take `JobModel#isEdit` as example:

```
get isEdit(): boolean {
    return this.formGroup.dirty || Job.isEdit(this.job.status)
}
```

I have no clue what's happening, but I know that if I do press a button or switch a tab eberywhere else, `sch-job-row-toolbar` receives the updated values.

All Components use `onPush` strategy.

Explanatory GIF:
[image]

And, interestingly, when I do the same thing from the first Tab, it works!
[image]

Tried using `Default` change detection strategy, but it's the same result.

Comment: Try calling `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` instead of `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan nada, same thing. I'm on this since a couple of hours, can't figure out. Have you seen the GIF?

Comment: @LppEdd look at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072065/after-child-has-been-initialised-operation-from-parent-component-on-child-dom-c/54072543#54072543)

Comment: @Abhishek I think it has nothing to do with my problem. I haven't got any error

Comment: Does it work in your first Tab, when it doesn't contain crons? And are there significant differences between both tabs?

Comment: @Batajus no, no differences, but it does receive an updated Cron array reference for every add/remove.
And yes, it works without any cron as a starting point in the Cron Tab

Comment: @ConnorsFan markForCheck() is not required until OnPush is used, since it marks a view and all of its ancestors dirty. This would result in rebuilding them in next tick.

Comment: @ManuBhardwaj - I made that suggestion because he was using the `OnPush` stategy (he had not tried the `Default` strategy at the time I made my comment).

Comment: @ConnorsFan Good to know. :)

Comment: hi @LppEdd so can someone post a final answer for this? thanks

Comment: hi @ManuBhardwaj hi  so can someone post a final answer for this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `@Input` and `@Output` in order to detect changes from parent to child component?
I would like to suggest you to use `@Input (parent => child)` and to use `@Output (child=> parent`) instead of `detectChanges()`.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.