# Angular ChangeDetectorRef - detectChanges

Tags: angular

The documentation for `detectChanges` states:

> Checks this view and its children

Does this mean it checks the direct children bindings, or does it check children recursively until it "hits" the deepest one?

Comment: Basically, yes, it will go recursively. More info here, https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/, for instance.

Comment: @Pac0 strangely enough, it doesn't seem so. I've posted a question regarding this a couple days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201990/angular-detectchanges-not-working-on-child-component

Comment: hum, I may have misundetrstood the question or misunderstood some rules in angular, but I'm trying to create a StackBlitz to clarify the point.

Comment: @Pac0 thank you! Eventually I'll create one with a similar environment as mine

Comment: In the meantime, related, maybe duplicate : [Angular2 change detection: ngOnChanges not firing for nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object)

Comment: @Pac0 thanks, I'll give it a read!

Comment: it talks about nested *objects*, not component, though

Comment: Now I am not sure to understand the question. We are talking about change detection for `Input()` values, right ? Then, you must explicitly bind a value from grand child to child, and from child to parent. Maybe that would be easier if you how a simple example you know that it's working, and another that you would like / expect to work.