# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError / Angular 4-Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I updated my code from Angular 4 to Angular 7 and suddenly this error started emerging. There are soo many articles on the internet about this but non seems to work. Can someone please point me out why I am getting this error?
Error comes in the Breadcrums

My Error

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData: false'. Current value: 'showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData: true'.

```
at viewDebugError (core.js:20342)
at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:20330)
at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:20432)
at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:23307)
at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:23292)
at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:23896)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23824)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent.html:6)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23813)
at checkNoChangesView (core.js:23191)
```

Home.Component.html

```
<div class="wrapper" >
  <navbar [metaData]="navBarMetadata" [userInfo]="navbarUserInfo" [helpButtonRoute]="navbarHelpButtonRoute"
        [menuItems]="sidebarRoutes" [settingsMenuItems]="settingsMenuItems"
        [languagesMenuItems]="languagesMenuItems"
        [rs_logo]="rs_logo"></navbar>
    <details-bar [breadscrumbsMetaData]="breadscrumbsMetaData" [breadcrumbsSiteMetaData]="breadcrumbsSiteMetaData"
             [showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData]="showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData"></details-bar>

  <div class="main-panel" #mainPanel (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <div class="container ">
      <div class="current-component">
        <simple-notifications [options]="notificationOptions"></simple-notifications>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Home.Component.ts

```
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    notificationOptions: any = AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_OPTIONS;
    sidebarRoutes: NavbarRouteInfo[];
    settingsMenuItems: NavbarRouteInfo[];
    navBarMetadata: NavBarMetadata[];
    navbarUserInfo: NavBarUserInfo;
    navbarHelpButtonRoute: string;
    rs_logo: string;
    languagesMenuItems: LanguageInfo[];
    breadscrumbsMetaData: BreadscrumbMetadata[];
    breadcrumbsSiteMetaData: BreadscrumbMetadata[];
    showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData: boolean;
    entityTypeList: RSEntityType[];
    @ViewChild('mainPanel') mainPanelDiv: ElementRef;
    activeAppKey: string;
    protected alive = true;
    private notificationTitles: { error: string };

    constructor(public notificationsManager: NotificationsManager,
          private authGuard: AppAuthGuard,
          private homeEventBus: HomeEventBus,
          private userManagementService: UserManagementService,
          private homeService: HomeService,
          private authService: AuthService,
          private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
          private translate: TranslateService,
          private dataService: DataService) {
          this.breadcrumbsSiteMetaData = [];
          this.showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData = false;
          this.activeAppKey = '';
          this.entityTypeList = [];
          this.initMessages();}

          initMessages() {
             this.translate.stream('home.msg').subscribe((res) => {
             this.notificationTitles = {
             'error': res['error']
             }
          }
     );

}

ngOnInit() {

    this.notificationsManager.showSpinner();
    this.translate.setDefaultLang
    (sessionStorage.getItem(AppConstants.LANGUAGE));
    this.subscribeEvents();
    this.initNavBar();
    this.initSideBar();
    this.initLanguageBar();
    this.notificationsManager.hideSpinner();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initNavBar();
    if (((this.activeAppKey) === undefined || (this.activeAppKey) === null) || 
    this.activeAppKey.trim().length === 0) {
    this.activeAppKey = sessionStorage.getItem(AppConstants.APP_KEY);
    }

    if (this.authGuard.isAccessTokenDefined()) {
    this.dataService.loadUserIdEmailList(this.activeAppKey);
    }
}

initNavBar() {
    this.rs_logo = environment.API_BASE_URL + '/' + 'resources/internal-assets/images?name=rs-logo.png';
    this.setNavBarMetaData();
    this.navbarHelpButtonRoute = AppConstants.HELP_ROUTE;
    this.navbarUserInfo = new NavBarUserInfo('assets/img/default-avatar.png', '');
    this.loadUserImg();
 }

 setNavBarMetaData() {
     this.translate.stream('navbar').subscribe((res) => {
         this.navBarMetadata = [{
             path: 'profile',
             params: {},
             title: res['profile'],
             index: -1
         }];
     });
 }


this.homeEventBus.breadcrumbsSiteMetaDataUpdateEvent$.subscribe(data => {
  if (data) {
    // this.fetchEntityTypes();
    this.showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData = true;
  } else {
    // this.breadcrumbsSiteMetaData = [];
    this.showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: look at this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072065/after-child-has-been-initialised-operation-from-parent-component-on-child-dom-c/54072543#54072543

Comment: when i add the ` private _cd: ChangeDetectionRef,` it says cannot find `ChangeDetectionRef`. Do u know where to import it?

Comment: From core module you have to import

Comment: Can you share some more code where you're changing the showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData? For the current value to be true, something other than what you have posted has to be changing it.

Comment: @OneLunchMan added the place where it becomes true at the end of the code ! thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of passing in the boolean with showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData, can you just make the homeEventBus public and async pipe the this.homeEventBus.breadcrumbsSiteMetaDataUpdateEvent$? `!!(homeEventBus.breadcrumbsSiteMetaDataUpdateEvent$ | async)`?

Comment: from where should i import asyn? rxjs/internal or rxjs-compact or angular/core ?

Comment: cannot just use `homeEventBus`, gives an error, have to use `this.homeEventBus`. then the site doesn't work

Comment: as a simpler solution the error you are getting is because you are updating the home component using its child component after the content has already been checked. So why not take the nav component out of the home component and use it  on its own?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this indicates a design flow, however, there are cases which the asynchronous pattern forces you to change things after angular checked it.

In order to re-initiate a change detection cycle, you have to

Import `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Inject it in your component,

```
public constructor(private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
```

When you are certain to have completed the changes, mark your component as changed, and trigger the change

```
this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

Please, be aware that you know control the detection cycle, therefore you must be sure you are not looping yourself asking to continuously to force the detection, otherwise you defeat the purpose of the all thing.

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
  this.homeEventBus.breadcrumbsSiteMetaDataUpdateEvent$
      .pipe(
          delay(0),
          tap(data => {
              if (data)
                this.showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData = true;
              else
                this.showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData = false;
            })
      ).subscribe();
```

or

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.homeEventBus.breadcrumbsSiteMetaDataUpdateEvent$.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        // this.fetchEntityTypes();
        this.showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData = true;
      } else {
        // this.breadcrumbsSiteMetaData = [];
        this.showBreadcrumbsSiteMetaData = false;
      }
    });
  });
```

---

your code might having issue as it modifying value of property in `ngAfterViewInit`, that might be cause of issue

so you should put you code of ngAfterViewInit as bel

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeout(() => {
    this.initNavBar();
    if (((this.activeAppKey) === undefined || (this.activeAppKey) === null) || 
    this.activeAppKey.trim().length === 0) {
    this.activeAppKey = sessionStorage.getItem(AppConstants.APP_KEY);
    }

    if (this.authGuard.isAccessTokenDefined()) {
    this.dataService.loadUserIdEmailList(this.activeAppKey);
    }
  }
}
```

for detail check : https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Comment: @OshanaDissanayake - have ytou tried `this.homeEventBus.breadcrumbsSiteMetaDataUpdateEvent$
      .pipe(
          delay(0),` one ?

Comment: @OshanaDissanayake - if both update is not working can you please share code at stackbiz